# Spring-boot application shutting down with no aperant reason

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot application that I have no idea why is shutting-down, there is no error on logs what I just have is this:

```
2020-05-12 16:01:47.489  INFO 21052 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2020-05-12 16:01:47.491  INFO 21052 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-12 16:01:47.493  INFO 21052 --- [       Thread-4] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-12 16:01:47.503  INFO 21052 --- [       Thread-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-05-12 16:01:47.513  INFO 21052 --- [       Thread-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

In the pom I use the following versions:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

I ran the project by:

```
java -jar myjar.jar >> myjar-2020-05-12.log &
```

I don't have idea what else I can share here to specify better the situation, I ran the project using

Comment: do you run the app on a distant machine ? If yes, then the cause is that the machine is hibernating or the session is timing-out, you need to add nohup to the command

Comment: yes, running on distant machine, linux CentOS server, this can hibernate? And session is no problem stop my ssh session, because I put the trailing &, so the expected behavior is to keep running. nohup you mean in ssh session?

Comment: thanks for answer by the way...

Comment: this is the way: `nohup java -jar myjar.jar >> myjar-2020-05-12.log &`

Comment: otherwise the process will be stopped after session timeout (after you logout from the session)

Comment: It run more then a week last time, but maybe is some side effect on something about the way I logout or something... so I rerun the application with your tip, if you want can post the answer and if still keep running tomorrow I mark as correct ;)

Comment: ok, I will post it as an answer for other people. I remember I had the same problem :)

Comment: great, I vote up by now, at least it make sense, hope gonna solve the situation, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run the app with a `nohup` to ignore the HUP signal (on logout) :

`nohup java -jar myjar.jar >> myjar-2020-05-12.log &`

Comment: Using this solution until today!